# Can't get result from the pyclustering object with reticulate

Tags: r, reticulate

I want to cluster some data in R with library from Python (`pyclustering`).
I am using `reticulate` package to do this:

```
library(reticulate)
# create some random array
np <- import("numpy", convert = FALSE)
dat <- np$random$rand(100,2)
# clustering with CURE
clus_cure <- import("pyclustering.cluster.cure")
clus_res <- clus_cure$cure(dat, 2)
clus_res$get_clusters()
```

But it returns `NULL`.

Please, where is a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with use of `pyclustering` library and not with `reticulate` or `R`. As indicated in the README [example](https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering), you need to run `process()` function on `<pyclustering.cluster.cure.cure>` object:

```
library(reticulate)
# create some random array
np <- import("numpy", convert = FALSE)
dat <- np$random$rand(10L,2L)
# clustering with CURE
clus_cure <- import("pyclustering.cluster.cure")
clus_res <- clus_cure$cure(data = dat, number_cluster=2L)
clus_res$process()
print(clus_res$get_clusters())
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2 3 8 0 1 7 4 9
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 5 6
```

Also, note that you need to explicitly specify integers, where expected